# Why won't my FlashQ triggers fire an off-camera flash on Nikon?

Tags: nikon, off-camera-flash, wireless-triggers, wireless-flash

I bought a pair of [FLashQ](http://flashq.myshopify.com/) wireless radio triggers for my Nikon D700 and SB-28. I can get the flash to fire by pressing the button on the receiver and the trigger connected to the SB-28. It will not flash when I press the shutter on the D700. What setting(s) do I need to have enabled on the camera to fire the flash when I take a shot? I have tried multiple setting in the bracketing/flash menu. I just cannot get it to work.

Comment: Silly question: are you sure it's not in the hotshoe backwards, and that it's seated all the way in place? I love those little triggers, but they're kind of fiddly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The trigger on the camera was seated the wrong way. The instruction manual for the FlashQ triggers was kinda lacking so I just went on intuition on how to place the transmitter on the D700 hot shoe. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Step one when working with flash triggers and off camera flashes:

- Be sure the batteries are properly charged enough to power your equipment.

Step two:

- Be sure everything is connected properly.

Step three:

- Be sure everything is turned on.

Step four:

- Be sure everything is set to the same channel.